# I need a mysql query that display month and the sum of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need a mysql query that display month and the sum of a column (md_price) ,sample of My Table :

```
run_date    |  md_price
01-Apr-2016 |  20
01-Apr-2016 |  30
01-Apr-2016 |  40
03-May-2016 |  20
04-May-2016 |  80
04-May-2016 |  60
```

...etc

I want it to be :

```
run_date    |  SUM(md_price)
  Apr       |  90
  May       |  160
```

..etc

can anyone help me with the query 
Note : run_date is in type varchar(11)

Comment: Look up `SUM(column_name)` in the manual and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Don't use `VARCHAR` to store dates. Use the proper data type `DATE` for it. You just make your life more difficult... and ours too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try proper conversion of therun_date string and group by

```
select month(str_to_date(run_date, '%d-%b-%Y')) my_month, sum(md_price)
from my_table 
group by   month(str_to_date(run_date, '%d-%b-%Y'))
```

or

```
select monthname(str_to_date(run_date, '%d-%b-%Y')) my_month, sum(md_price)
from my_table 
group by   month(str_to_date(run_date, '%d-%b-%Y'))
```

Comment: didn`t work it says : Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'MONTHNAME'

Comment: it works after I relocate the parentheses : month(str_to_date(run_date,'%d-%b-%Y'))